# Write an equation using constants e, i, pi and phi

Tags: logical-deduction

Without using numbers and using only permitted math operators, write an equation using the constants $e$, $i$, $\pi$ and $\phi$.
Allowed operators..exponent...multiplication..subtraction...only. Use the constants minimal number of times.

Comment: There are many answers; I believe this is too broad.

Comment: Excluding trivial...answer will be less than 10 characters

Comment: Hi @Uvc, welcome to Puzzling SE! (Take the [tour] if you haven't already!) Unfortunately, as your question stands, it is too broad and thus [will likely be closed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Please see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for information about what is considered on-topic here. Thanks!

Comment: It has a unique nontrivial solution with less than 10 characters

Comment: Can you clarify as to what a "character" and "math operator" is?

Comment: What counts as "nontrivial?"

Comment: Can those constants be used more than once?

Comment: @noedne well, trivial is like $e + i + \pi + \phi = e + i + \pi + \phi$

Comment: @athin That is one example, but can you give a rule?

Comment: Hmm, right.. defining non-trivial as $LHS \neq RHS$ won't do..

Comment: @Uvc you still need to define what a "concise" equation is, since what is concise to you might not be the same for me

Comment: Edited further to clarify...thx

Comment: @Uvc So, what do you expect? A new Euler will come and discover out of a sudden a new identity? That's not a puzzle question.

Comment: Just a mere mortal would do..main reason for creating the puzzle is to tie in the key constants in one equation utilizing the unique property of phi!! without using any numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this

> $e^{i \pi} = \phi - (\phi \times \phi)$

Comment: Clever! Wish I didn't reach my daily voting limit!

Comment: Why don't use ROT13(artngvir cuv bire cuv) on RHS?

Comment: @athin indeed, that would use less symbols, but the original answer above showcases the beauty behind each of the values via their delicate properties (e.g. like how $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$ and the obvious LHS). But eh, aesthetics over poetics! :D

Comment: Thanks Mr.Pie...every math book I have seen so far mention famous Euler equation but I have not seen it tied to the unique quadratic equation involving the golden ratio..

Comment: @Uvc it is simply a matter of substitution, as a matter of fact. I mean, given that $\phi$ is the root of a quadratic equation, it is paired with another root. Since this quadratic is the minimal polynomial, it follows that $\phi$ and its conjugate $1-\phi$ are the two distinct roots, respectively; so I could even tie Euler's identity with the latter root instead, if I pleased, but we are not given that in the actual puzzle itself :)

Comment: True..this way you have all key constants tied together  in one equation without any numbers.